# Is there a way to execute arp -a cmd command in python script?

Tags: python, networking, arp, nmap

I want to get mac address of all the device connected to network. [in a script - all windows environment]

I decided to use python for that. I have used nmap for it.

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')
#nm.scan(hosts='192.168.1.0/24', arguments='-n -sP -PE -PA21,23,80,3389')
nm.scan(hosts = '192.168.1.0/24', arguments = '-n -sP -PE -T5')
for host in nm.all_hosts():
    mac = nm[host]['addresses']['mac']
    print("mac " + mac)
```

[The problem with this method is that, sometime it misses few devices. Meaning, 
If there are 5 devices connected to router, and I run the script first time, it will return only one or two devices. Next time I run the script it will return all 5, third time may be only one...like that.]

Where as if I open command prompt and do,

```
arp -a
```

It works perfectly every time.

So my question is that, is there a way I could parse the result from cmd in python script?

I looked onto os.popen(..??..),
But I am not able to understand exactly how can I do that? 
Is there any good library for this?https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arprequest/0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. You probably want to use the `check_output` method:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(("arp", "-a"))
# Parse output here
```

`check_output` will return a `str` object in python 2, and a `bytes` object in python 3 which you can convert with `output.decode("ascii")` for example.